# React - most efficient way to map.filter.map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following bit of react code. I have an array of groups and an array of menu items with respective groups. I want to show menu items by group like this...

```
groups.GroupDetail.map(group => {
    return (
    menuList.filter(menuItems => { return menuItems.group == group.name }).map(item => {
      return <p style={{ width: '100%' }}>{item.name}</p>
    })
  )
})
```

Is there a more efficient way to iterate through the groups and filter for the respective menu items? I feel like there should be a higherlevel js array method I could use.

Comment: you can use `.reduce()`

Comment: if its useful for you, you could do something like groupBy ( https://www.30secondsofcode.org/js/s/group-by ) to group the menu items by each group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.filter` followed by `.map` is fine, but it'd be more concise to take advantage of the implicit return of ES6 arrow functions:

```
groups.GroupDetail.map(
    ({ name }) => menuList
        .filter(({ group }) => group === name })
        .map(({ name }) => <p style={{ width: '100%' }}>{name}</p>)
};
```

`reduce` is an option, but I'm not so happy with it:

```
groups.GroupDetail.map(
    ({ detailName }) => menuList
        .reduce((a, { group, name }) => group === detailName ? [...a, <p style={{ width: '100%' }}>{name}</p>] : a, [])
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution. Using [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), you can get the result as a combination of `map` and `filter`.

```
groups.GroupDetail.map(group => {
  return (
    menuList.reduce((filtered, menuItem) => { 
      if (menuItem.group == group.name) {
        filtered.push(<p style={{ width: '100%' }}>{item.name}</p>)
      }
      return filtered;
    }, [])
  )
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use hooks you can use [useMemo](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) whit `menuItems` or/and `groups` as dependencies (depending of your code) and you can save "memo" the Component and pre-compute when any of this values has changed.

You can have the same effect if you create a Component with `menuItems` and `groups` as parameters (And only will re-render if any of both vars changes)